# How to start my Angular Server

Tags: angularjs, node.js

A couple of days ago I've started learning angular and today I've stepped over [this project](https://github.com/itswadesh/angularcode-authentication-app) which looks very promissing. What commands should I use or add to my project in order to make it run in a browser? Thank you a lot

Comment: the project you listed is php, not node.js

Answer (score 1):

Generally [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) and [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) might help. Proper configuration will make the development process super-easy. 
If the project is well organised you can start working on it like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/itswadesh/angularcode-authentication-app.git myapp
cd myapp
npm install
npm start
```

In the second link look at the section named "Keep the app transpiling and running", here's the command shown there:

```
npm start
```

The above generally runs the server, keeps track of changes in files and acts on them - translating code to typescript/javascript and re-running the server with changed files.

Comment: first, this is angular.js, not angular2.  second, the project that was linked is PHP, so `npm start` isn't really valid.